# Using promise library for more than one module

Tags: node.js, bluebird

i've node js program with some several **different** module which the file system module (fs),I want to use the bluebird functionality and for that I need to use the following code,my question is if I need to do it once in my node application or to o it for each file?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

Comment: Each file. though, you could have probably figured that out by trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it in a top level JS file that loads the other modules, you have to do it just once.

This works because the response of `require()` will be cached by Node.js, which means that calling `Promise.promisifyAll` will modify the cached data, which is subsequently shared amongst other modules.

For instance:

```
// a.js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs      = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var b       = require('./b');

// b.js
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('promisified?', 'readFileAsync' in fs);
```

Comment: Thanks,just to verify if I do that in server.js (my entry point program when I create express listener ) this will be valid to all the sub modules which is invoked latter on in the application ?and if I do in some module later on in the process require('fs') it will have the bluebird functionlity?

Comment: @JhonDree as long as the modules are part of the same application, it'll work (but the proof of the pudding is in the eating... :-)